# SSRS gives a Teradata error, but none of the databases are Teradata databases

Tags: ssrs-2012

I have a very strange thing occurring with one of my SSRS reports.  The report in question started timing out ever since we upgraded the database servers (not the report server) to MSSQL 2012.  I had the DBAs look into it and they discovered that the report server was trying to instantiate a Teradata report server extension.  The problem is, none of the databases being used by the report is a Teradata database.  Can anyone shed some light on why this may be happening?